# Disabling the Keyboard settings button on the Virtual keyboard - Windows 10 LTSC

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, kiosk, virtual-keyboard

I have a touchscreen PC (kiosk) running Windows 10 LTSC. It's gonna run without a physical keyboard in production, so I've set it up to show a virtual keyboard using the following setting:
[image]

The keyboard looks nice, and does everything I need it to do, but there's this Settings button in the top left corner I want to get rid of:

[image]

The problem is this allows the user to switch the keyboard to a different layout, including this obnoxiously tiny one:

[image]

The next user that comes to use the kiosk may not be tech-savvy enough to figure out he can switch the keyboard back to the standard layout, so he'll be stuck trying to use the tiny obnoxious one.

The only advice I've found so far was "In Local Group Policy Editor go to User Configuration > Administartive Templates > Control Panels and enable "Prohibit access to Control Panel and PC Settings". That didn't help, the keyboard settings button was still visible. (though it did prevent me from going to Settings and making that screenshot on top of the post).

Please advise?